# Removing entries from syntastic

Tags: python, vim, syntastic, flake8

I'm working on a project that uses gettext and so end up with a lot of error results in syntastic (using flake8) that say:

```
 undefined name '_'
```

i don't want to remove W802, but i would like to suppress those messages by grepping out the string before syntastic parses it. I've tried every combination of

```
let g:syntastic_python_flake8_tail=' | grep -v "F821 undefined name ._."'
```

i can think of, but i get shell returned 1 or other errors.

How can i set syntastic to remove these errors without removing all F821 errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found that you can add the following to the `[flake8]` section of either your global `~/.config/flake8` or project `tox.ini`, `setup.cfg` files

```
[flake8]
builtins = _
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `g:syntastic_python_flake8_quiet_messages` to remove messages:

```
let g:syntastic_python_flake8_quiet_messages = { "regex": "F821" }
```